# how to use inputstream as params in android asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am making an android application to track stock details and i am going to retrieve the data through csv (yahoo finance). As I know, in android 4.0, network connection can't be done on the main thread. Therefore, I am going to use asynctask to make the connection. However, i face some problems with the params. I would like to ask that can inputstream type use as params?

```
public class StockDetails extends Activity {
    private InputStream is = null;
    private BufferedReader reader = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stock_details);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String stockNo = i.getStringExtra(MainActivity.STOCK_NO).toString();
        Log.i("Stock No", stockNo);
        String strURL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="+ stockNo +".HK&f=nsl1opc1";
        Log.i("URL", strURL);
        class HostConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {
            private Exception ex;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            protected InputStream doInBackground(String... urls) {
                try {
                    // defaultHttpClient
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    return httpEntity.getContent();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.ex = e;
                    return null;
                } 
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(InputStream is) {
                super.onPostExecute(is);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            }
        }
        new HostConnection().execute(strURL);
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                String[] RowData = line.split(",");
                String name = RowData[0];
                String symbol = RowData[1];
                String currPrice = RowData[2];
                String open = RowData[3];
                String prevClose = RowData[4];
                String change = RowData[5];

                TextView stockName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stockName);
                stockName.setText(name);
                TextView stockSymbol = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stockSym);
                stockSymbol.setText(symbol);
                TextView stockCurrPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currPrice);
                stockCurrPrice.setText(currPrice);
                TextView stockOpen = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.open);
                stockOpen.setText(open);
                TextView stockPrevClose = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prevClose);
                stockPrevClose.setText(prevClose);
                TextView stockChange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.change);
                stockChange.setText(change);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        ...
    }

}
```

The above is my code and it can't execute the statement `return httpEntity.getContent();` and jump into the exception part. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: hello, better way it to read all content from inputstream and convert it into string use string

Comment: Hello KPBird, how can i do that? sorry, i am a beginner in android app programming

Comment: and do i have problems in using asynctask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `InputStream` as the Result value type is perfectly legal, as well as any other class. But you must be aware that an `AsyncTask` executes asynchronously, so if you call `new HostConnection().execute(strURL);` and then immediately try to use variables that are being initialized inside the `AsyncTask`, you're gonna be in trouble. You should wait for the `AsyncTask` to finish its execution by defining some kind of callback mechanism, or in your case, as the `AsyncTask` is an inner class, you can just push all the code related to `BufferedReader` to the `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait to read the whole input stream untill `onPostExecute` is called read it in `doInBackground`.

When you read an important result, send it back to the UI thread by implementing [`onProgressUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) but you should probably process the `InputStream` in the background thread and not return it as a result, because you might run into buffering issues.